# Is there an open source operating system I can run on an old Power Macintosh 9600?

Tags: macos, mac, operating-systems, open-source, powerpc

I'd like to get some use out of an old Power Macintosh 9600 with a 350mhz PowerPC 604e and tinker with it. Is there any open source OS I can install on it?

Comment: This might be a better question for [Retro Computing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) but that machine can run anything from System 7.1 to 9. You can probably pick up CD Installers for pence these days. A quick Google says there are downloadable versions too. I'm not certain about the strict 'legality' of that but I'm pretty sure the lawyers are not going to be greatly concerned about a 20-year-old OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are BSD distributions and a handful of Linux distros that support the PowerPC architecture.  You can see a list on [DistroWatch.com](https://distrowatch.com/search.php?architecture=powerpc).  I just glanced at them, some were not that old.  These OSs will most likely be the most useful, even if not up to the latest version as you would find for a PC or Mac .

[Haiku](https://www.haiku-os.org/) is an open source OS that is currently in development and has a PowerPC build.  Haiku just released its first beta about a week ago.  Glancing at the page, it looks like the PPC version needs to be manually [compiled](https://www.haiku-os.org/guides/building/compiling-powerpc/).  Ive played with the Haiku beta on PC and it still needs *a lot* of work.  You wont find as much software as the BSD or Linux distros.  However, it is under active development and you could port software over and compile it...  In my opinion, I would stick with Linux/BSD.

There were other open source OSs for PowerPC, such as OpenSolaris, other Linux distros, and others.  However, development for these platforms died a *very* long time ago.  You may be able to find old versions on the web.  However, I dont think these would be as useful as a more modern(ish) BSD or Ubuntu distro.